# Is is possible to travel when applying for a new visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, international-travel

I am Bangladeshi currently in France applying for a Spanish visa. The visa office will hold the passport for few days. Is it possible to travel during this time?

Comment: You're asking if you can travel internationally without your passport? Unless you hold more than 1 travel document (like 2 passports from different nationalities) I don't see how this could be possible.

Comment: Yes or the other way why they generally holds the passport while issuing a visa? No I have only one passport. I think I have got the answer..

Comment: Why are you applying for a Spanish visa if you are in France?  They are both in the Schengen area.  What visa do you have for France?

Comment: I have Schengen visa but they are saying for an internship in Spain I will need another visa

Comment: Some countries will issue you another passport. You might be able to get another Bengladeshi passport, but even that will take a while and by the time you manage to get one you'd probably have your original passport back.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But they didn't hold my passport, they returned my passport and said I need to bring it back when they will give the visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travelling internationally without any travel document is between very difficult and impossible depending on the details. If you need to leave the Schengen area and re-enter, you definitely need a passport. You would in all likelihood be refused boarding by the airline or blocked from leaving the Schengen area by the border guards.

If you are travelling within the Schengen area and have a residence card, it might still be possible in practice even if it's not explicitly allowed. If you have nothing at all, you would probably still be able to physically cross the border but could get in serious trouble if you are found in another country with no document establishing your status.

Even travelling in France is not without risk. Technically, you are supposed [to be able to prove you are in France legally](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F31208.xhtml) (i.e. show your visa) at any time if the police asks. If you don't have your passport on you, they could detain you for some time to check your status.

Obviously, the requirement to surrender your passport for a visa application puts you in an awkward situation but there is no easy way around that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But they didn't hold my passport, they returned my passport and said I need to bring it when they will issue the visa.

Comment: @eagleye That's good news. You might want to post that as answer and accept it instead of mine!

Comment: The didn't hold the passport that's another case. If they would hold the passport then your answer is valid, right?